# No module named machinery

Tags: python, py2exe

I am trying to make exe using `py2exe` in Python. When I import `py2exe` I am getting error like this:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import py2exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe-0.9.2.0-py2.7-win32.egg\py2exe\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    patch_distutils()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe-0.9.2.0-py2.7-win32.egg\py2exe\patch_distutils.py", line 68, in patch_distutils
    from . import distutils_buildexe
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe-0.9.2.0-py2.7-win32.egg\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 91, in <module>
    from . import runtime
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe-0.9.2.0-py2.7-win32.egg\py2exe\runtime.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .dllfinder import Scanner, pydll
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe-0.9.2.0-py2.7-win32.egg\py2exe\dllfinder.py", line 7, in <module>
    from importlib.machinery import EXTENSION_SUFFIXES
ImportError: No module named machinery
```

Can any body help me fixing this out. I am not getting machinery module any where.

Comment: How did you install the py2exe module?

Comment: I downloaded it from source and ran python `setup.py install`

Comment: `importlib` was added in Python 3. Do you also have Python 3 installed on your computer, and what exact link was used to download the py2exe source?

Answer (score 9):

I just ran into this myself. I had installed 0.9 from pypi as well. If you look at the pypi page here [py2exe on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/0.9.2.0), you'll see that the download only supports Python 3.3 and later and you should use [the 0.6 download from here](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=15583). I deleted the 0.9 egg after installing 0.6 and it worked after that.

Comment: And the listed exe's are installers that place the py2exe in the proper location on the harddrive.

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue, because i had version py2exe0.9 and it is not supported for python2.7.

I downloaded lower version from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/0.6.9/py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.7.exe/download

and it works.